# symfony APi to YAML format for swagger

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, swagger

Does anyone know how to convert a API based on Symfony2 to Yaml format? 
I would like to use it for Swagger. 
Up until now I was using the bundle NelmioApiDocBundle

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you using a Symfony 2.* and written all api's using Nelmio `@ApiDoc` then yes you should add this routing inside of routing.yml
`nelmio_api_swagger:
    resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/swagger_routing.yml"
    prefix: /api-docs`

and run `php app/console api:swagger:dump`

and then access using `/api-docs`

To better understanding [click here](https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/swagger-support.html)

Comment: That what i'm currently using.
I would now to convert it like in swagger hub which I can split the editor and check the yml while having the documentation

Comment: just add the above routing to your routing.yml and after running commands access http://yourhost/api-docs, if still you face problem right here...
To test locally and editing swagger you need to setup this https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui and copy paste swagger output and setup base url to the api and then you could test api's from swagger or directly access or access on web and paste the output of your api-doc here https://editor.swagger.io/